# strtotime with variable in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, variables, strtotime

I've tried to change this code:

```
function filter_where( $where = '' ) {
$where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-365 days')) . "'";
return $where;}
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
```

into this one:

```
function filter_where( $where = '' ) {
$where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-'.$timestamp.' days')) ."'";
return $where;}
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
```

You may noticed that I've tried to put variable $timestamp inside strtotime. However the code doesn't work. Did I do the correct syntax to put the variable within the strtotime PHP function?

I appreciate any kind of help.

Answer (score 0):

It is the correct code *if* `$timestamp` contains a positive integer.

**However**, in the context of that function and without the `global` keyword, `$timestamp` is undefined and `null`.

Do you mean to pass that variable as an argument of `and_where()`?

Comment: I've defined $timestamp with 30 (just for testing). But it still doesn't work.

I don't quite understand with your question, but I just want to return the number of posts with within the last $timestamp days.

Comment: Oh, I see the problem. The value of $timeframe is not recognized in that filter.
How to pass value of $timeframe to that function?

Comment: @xolomon Pass it as an argument to the function.