# Passing a Variable in strtotime() function in PHP

Tags: php, variables, date, strtotime

Similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301213/strtotime-with-variable-in-wordpress), but there was no answer to my specific issue.

The current date is 2011-12-14, for reference in case this question is viewed in the future.

I tried this:

```
$maxAge = $row['maxAge']; // for example, $row['maxAge'] == 30
$cutoff = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-$maxAge days'));
```

And it returns the following value for `$cutoff: 1969-12-31`

And I tried this:

```
$maxAge = $row['maxAge']; // for example, $row['maxAge'] == 30
$cutoff = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-' . $maxAge . ' days'));
```

And it returns the following value for `$cutoff: 2011-03-14`

How can I pass this variable successfully into the `strtotime()` function so that it calculates the amount of days to subtract correctly?

For example, if `$maxAge == 30` and the current date is 2011-12-14, then `$cutoff` should be 2011-11-14

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use double quotes:

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-$maxAge days"));
```

Answer (score 4):

Use double quotes:

```
$cutoff = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-$maxAge days"));
```

However, if you're doing simple calculations like this, you can simply your code by not using strtotime, like so:

```
$date = getdate();
$cutoff = date('Y-m-d', mktime( 0, 0, 0, $date['mon'], $date['mday'] - $maxAge, $date['year']));
echo $cutoff;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use either a double quoted or a heredoc string in PHP for expanded variables. Single quoted and nowdoc strings do not expand variables.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing